# Get records from last hour

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-asa

I have this query:

```
SELECT Field1, OrderFor, Writeback, Actshipdate, Orderstatus, receivedate, receivetime
FROM orderinfo, shippinginfo
WHERE orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid
AND shippinginfo.custid = '37782'
AND receivedate =  DATE(NOW())
AND receivetime = ???????
```

I am using Sybase adaptive server anywhere and trying to get records for the last hour.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

try this !!

```
SELECT Field1, OrderFor, Writeback, Actshipdate, Orderstatus, receivedate, receivetime
    FROM orderinfo, shippinginfo
    WHERE orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid
    AND shippinginfo.custid = '37782'
    AND receivedate =  DATE(NOW())
     AND receivetime > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try below query:

```sql
SELECT Field1, OrderFor, Writeback, Actshipdate, Orderstatus, receivedate, receivetime 
  FROM orderinfo, shippinginfo
  WHERE orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid
    AND shippinginfo.custid = '37782'
    AND receivedate =  DATE(NOW())
    AND receivetime >= (sysdate-1/24);
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to TeamDataViz's answer. Just a little more readable IMO.

```
SELECT Field1, OrderFor, Writeback, Actshipdate, Orderstatus, receivedate, receivetime
FROM orderinfo, shippinginfo
WHERE orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid
AND shippinginfo.custid = '37782'
WHERE receivedate BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

The WHERE Clause becomes even easier if you only wish to focus on records by Past DAY

```
WHERE receivedate > GETDATE() - 12
```