# How to select row which has 3 hours ago

Tags: php, datetime, select, mysqli

i have table which has column **completed_at** type **(datetime)**

i am inserting date in it by **php date('Y-m-d H:i:s')** 2016-05-17 00:00:14

I want to select data which has 3 hours ago

```
<?php
$sql = "Select `id`,`file` from `uploader` where `completed_at` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR";
        $DB = new DB();

        mysqli_query($DB->db_connect(), $sql);

?>
```

but it gives me wrong answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records from last hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743850/get-records-from-last-hour)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT FROM table_name
 WHERE completed_at  < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

Comment: thank you for answer Jayesh i echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') // 2016-05-17 06:47:30 but it gives me also this record 2016-05-17 06:41:29 which has not yet 3 hours