# Sql Query to find data only from last hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have An table As Follow

[image]

*I need Data Only From Last Hour.*  Following query i tried using Reference.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_otp` 
WHERE `date` = '$todate'
AND datetime > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

I Dont Know This But I tried Using **[This Refferance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743850/get-records-from-last-hour)**

But It Not Work For Me .
So Any Help Would be useful.

Comment: What results do you get using your query and the sample data provided?

Comment: `FUNCTION tbl_name.DATEADD does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATE_SUB and NOW() functions in query

```
SELECT count(*) as lasthour_count 
FROM user_otp 
WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 3):

`DATEADD` and `GETDATE()` exist in SQL Server.

In MySQL, your conditions should be:

```
WHERE `datetime` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

While `date = '$todate'` condition is redundant and should be removed.

Here's a documentation in [MySQL DateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use DATE_SUB function for fetch last one hour data. I edited your code below -

```
SELECT * FROM `user_otp` 
WHERE `date` = '$todate'
AND datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime>=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);
datetime>= DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

These are the two options you can use